# How to use user uploaded image in Django template?

Tags: django, django-file-upload, django-media

My problem is I am unable to use images in templates that are uploaded by an admin with admin interface. I have configured my settings and URLs according to documentation.

In browser inspect element it is showing

```
<img src(unknown)>
```

Uploaded image by an admin using admin interface is stored in the /media/ which is media root.

Location of the image is

```
/media/img/imagename.jpg
```

settings.py

```
# media
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py (my project url file)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

## urlpatterns here

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

models.py

```
class AboutMe(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
##  other fields
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    aboutme = models.AboutMe.objects.all()
    context = {'information': aboutme,}
    return render(request, 'portfolio/index.html', context)
```

template/index.html

```
{% for info in information %}
<img src="{{ info.inage.url }}"/> 
<div class="name-profile t-center">
  <h5 class="uppercase">{{info.name}}</h5>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is that a typo there - `{{ info.inage.url }}`? Should be `image`.

Comment: Hello xyres,
Thank you for mentioning the solution. Yes it was a typo that escape my eyes.

Now the link is working but the image is not showing. 
N:B: I have added height and width in my html file

Comment: <img src="{{ info.image.url }}" height=100px width=100px/>

Comment: @MahabubElahiShojib did you include {% load staticfiles %} tag in your template?

Comment: Is the image avilable in right directory e.g. Media? If yes, check <p>{{info.image}}</p> is it showing the correct path? And also remove this line, `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)`

Comment: hello @BidhanMajhi 
I tried but its not working
<p>{{info.image}}</p> showing img/image.jpg 
actual image location in /media/img/jpg so i guess the url is working

Comment: (If you can, please refrain from adding voting advice, or lengthy boilerplate about how much you searched. Readers expect everyone to search, and we surely don't want millions of questions making a point of it `:-)`. If a reader finds a duplicate, then don't worry about it - it is possible that for any given question, you missed one. It happens.)